# background-image in css style doesn't work in laravel with tailwind

Tags: html, css, laravel, styles, tailwind-css

background image doesn't appear, the image path is correct, I test it with  it is worked >>

```
<div class="flex items-end justify-end w-full h-56"
     style="background-image: {{url("/storage/images/services/".$order->image)}}">
    <a href="{{route('services.details', $order)}}">
        <button
            class="p-2 mx-5 -mb-4 text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-full hover:bg-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:bg-blue-500">
            <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"
                 stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                 stroke="currentColor">
                <path
                    d="M3 3h2l.4 2M7 13h10l4-8H5.4M7 13L5.4 5M7 13l-2.293 2.293c-.63.63-.184 1.707.707 1.707H17m0 0a2 2 0 100 4 2 2 0 000-4zm-8 2a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="px-5 py-3">
    <h3 class="text-gray-700 uppercase">{{ $order->name }}</h3>
    <span class="mt-2 text-gray-500">{{ $order->price }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the url in a the css `url()` function as well:

```
background-image: url({{ url('storage/images/services/' . $order->image) }})"
```

[url() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url())

[background-image docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)